# I need an alternative to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: linux, ide, visual-studio-2012

Hey I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask and sorry if its not, But I'm needing an alternative to Visual Studio 2012 for Linux and I found 2 so far called Netbean and Eclipse, Out of those or any other ones you guys may know of which is the closest or similar to VS 2012? Thank you for your time guys.

Comment: What kind of code do you plan to write?  C#?  On linux?  Try [monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)

Comment: In what language/platform do you to program?

Comment: To @madth3, I'm currently working with C# HTML/XHTML, JAVA and using PTVS for Python as well. I'm not all to familiar with using Linux distro's but about to install on a separate partition Mint.

Comment: @Danny, I Just checked that out and thank you. I'll try it out as soon as Mint is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several IDEs available on Linux.  Here's my short list:

- For C#/VB.NET/Mono: [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)
- For Java/html/javascript/python/ruby/php/and so much more!: [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html?IU)
- For C/C++, there are several alternatives: [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/junosr1), [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html), [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), [KDevelop](http://kdevelop.org/)

But that's not all of them, not even close! There is a much longer list of [IDEs for Linux](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Devtools/ides.html), and also matrices of [IDEs by language and platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments).

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also use `emacs`, `gedit`, `geany` .... and you don't need any IDE for coding.

Comment: It's all well and good to say you don't need an IDE, which is technically true. I use gedit for scripting and stuff. But for a medium+ project, a good IDE saves a *lot* of time and headache.